# Converting CSV to hierarchichal XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-1.0, transform, xslt-grouping

I need to create an XSLT to convert a CSV (comma separated file) into hierarchical XML.

This is the input file:

```
<root>
L11,L12,L21,L22,L31,L32
1,A,1,C,1,G
1,A,1,C,2,H
1,A,2,D,1,I
1,A,2,D,2,J
2,B,1,E,1,K
2,B,1,E,2,L
2,B,2,F,1,M
2,B,2,F,2,N
</root>
```

This is desired output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Level1>
    <L11>1</L11>
    <L12>A</L12>
    <Level2>
      <L21>1</L11>
      <L22>C</L12>
      <Level3>
        <L31>1</L31>
        <L32>G</L32>
      </Level3>
      <Level3>
        <L31>2</L31>
        <L32>H</L32>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
    <Level2>
      <L21>2</L11>
      <L22>D</L12>
      <Level3>
        <L31>1</L31>
        <L32>I</L32>
      </Level3>
      <Level3>
        <L31>2</L31>
        <L32>J</L32>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </Level1>
  <Level1>
    <L11>2</L11>
    <L12>B</L12>
    <Level2>
      <L21>1</L11>
      <L22>E</L12>
      <Level3>
        <L31>1</L31>
        <L32>K</L32>
      </Level3>
      <Level3>
        <L31>2</L31>
        <L32>L</L32>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
    <Level2>
      <L21>2</L11>
      <L22>F</L12>
      <Level3>
        <L31>1</L31>
        <L32>M</L32>
      </Level3>
      <Level3>
        <L31>2</L31>
        <L32>N</L32>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </Level1>
</Document>
```

I've been trying to find some example online, however couldn't find anything similar. I've never done XSLT transformations before so I'd appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

**Update 1**: I am thinking of a 2-step transformation. E.g. first step is to transform CSV to XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <row><L11>1</L11><L12>A</L12><L21>1</L12><L31>C</L31><L32>1</L31><L32>G</L32></row>
  <row><L11>1</L11><L12>A</L12><L21>1</L12><L31>C</L31><L32>2</L31><L32>H</L32></row>
  <row><L11>1</L11><L12>A</L12><L21>2</L12><L31>D</L31><L32>1</L31><L32>I</L32></row>
  <row><L11>1</L11><L12>A</L12><L21>2</L12><L31>D</L31><L32>2</L31><L32>J</L32></row>
  <row><L11>2</L11><L12>B</L12><L21>1</L12><L31>E</L31><L32>1</L31><L32>K</L32></row>
  <row><L11>2</L11><L12>B</L12><L21>1</L12><L31>E</L31><L32>2</L31><L32>L</L32></row>
  <row><L11>2</L11><L12>B</L12><L21>2</L12><L31>F</L31><L32>1</L31><L32>M</L32></row>
  <row><L11>2</L11><L12>B</L12><L21>2</L12><L31>F</L31><L32>2</L31><L32>N</L32></row>   
</Document>
```

And a second step is to transform that XML into the desired format using some sort of grouping.
I don't mind having 2 transformations if there's no other way to achieve that.

Any advice please?

**Update 2**: Microsoft .NET Framework XSLT processor will be used.

If the abstract example is hard to read you can see a real-life example of the required transformation here: http://servingxml.sourceforge.net/examples/#timesheets-eg

As I understand, using a single transformation is impossible, so if someone could show me how to transform an XML from the **Update 1** format to the desired XML format, half of the job would done and I will accept that answer.

Comment: XSLT is for XML.  If you are using XSLT 1.0 this will be painful. (unless you can write an extension... at which point you should just do the conversion in code.)

Comment: @Matthew There are some examples online for transforming CSV to XML using XSLT 1.0, however they wouldn't be nested (hierarchical) XML's. In my scenario I need an output XML with 3 levels. I don't mind using a 2-step approach: first transform CSV into a single-level XML, and then use grouping to achieve the desired result. I just need an example for such a grouping XSLT as I haven't done such transformations before.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the required transformation?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It can be timesheet entries such as in http://servingxml.sourceforge.net/examples/#timesheets-eg or it can be something else e.g. invoice header, lines and sublines. The input file is flat CSV, the accepted file format is XML, the only available transformation tool is XSLT.

Comment: The timesheet example is pretty self-explanatory; your abstract example is not. And there is no way that a single stylesheet will serve both. -- Also tell us which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using, as this could really use some extension functions.

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible.  I said it's painful.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That would be Microsoft .NET Framework XSLT processor working behind the scene, that is I cannot write .NET code to do transformations programmatically. I wanted to simplify the input file a bit because my real-life example is much larger and more complex. I just need to understand how to deal with a simple example first, that will allow me to adapt it to my complex scenario.

Comment: Would an example using the  timesheet input serve your purpose?

Comment: @michael.hor257k That would be awesome, yes. In my scenario I am not using attributes so instead of `<TimePeriod start="2/9/2004" finish="2/15/2004">` I would need `<TimePeriod><Start>2/9/2004</Start><Finish>2/15/2004</Finish></TimePeriod>`, however if it is more difficult to achieve I will be grateful for any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, I have modified your input slightly, so that the labels make some sense:

**XML**

```
<root>
GroupName,GroupValue,SubGroupName,SubGroupValue,ItemName,ItemValue
1,A,1,C,1,G
1,A,1,C,2,H
1,A,2,D,1,I
1,A,2,D,2,J
2,B,1,E,1,K
2,B,1,E,2,L
2,B,2,F,1,M
2,B,2,F,2,N
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="row" use="cell[1]"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="row" use="concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- tokenize csv -->
    <xsl:variable name="rows">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="root"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="data">
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rows)/row[position() > 1]">
            <row>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'cell'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <document>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($data)/row[count(. | key('k1', cell[1])[1]) = 1]">
            <group>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cell[1]"/>
                </name>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cell[2]"/>
                </value>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', cell[1])[count(. | key('k2', concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3]))[1]) = 1]">
                    <subgroup>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[3]"/>
                        </name>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[4]"/>
                        </value>
                        <items>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('k2', concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3]))">
                                <item>
                                    <name>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="cell[5]"/>
                                    </name>
                                    <value>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="cell[6]"/>
                                    </value>
                                </item>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </items>
                    </subgroup>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="name" select="'row'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <group>
      <name>1</name>
      <value>A</value>
      <subgroup>
         <name>1</name>
         <value>C</value>
         <items>
            <item>
               <name>1</name>
               <value>G</value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <name>2</name>
               <value>H</value>
            </item>
         </items>
      </subgroup>
      <subgroup>
         <name>2</name>
         <value>D</value>
         <items>
            <item>
               <name>1</name>
               <value>I</value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <name>2</name>
               <value>J</value>
            </item>
         </items>
      </subgroup>
   </group>
   <group>
      <name>2</name>
      <value>B</value>
      <subgroup>
         <name>1</name>
         <value>E</value>
         <items>
            <item>
               <name>1</name>
               <value>K</value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <name>2</name>
               <value>L</value>
            </item>
         </items>
      </subgroup>
      <subgroup>
         <name>2</name>
         <value>F</value>
         <items>
            <item>
               <name>1</name>
               <value>M</value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <name>2</name>
               <value>N</value>
            </item>
         </items>
      </subgroup>
   </group>
</document>
```

**Note:**

1. The element names are hard-coded into the stylesheet and not taken from the input (although that too would be possible with more effort);
2. You may have to use the `msxsl:node-set()` function instead of the EXSLT one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the data you have presented is not XML, so to tackle that problem you would at least need XSLT 2.0 like implemented by Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Exselt or Altova. I think in a first step one could transform the data in comma separated lines into XML elements, then in a second step one could transform the input, using grouping. It seems to me a problem where a composite grouping key use as supported in XSLT 3.0 could help so the following is XSLT 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math array mf" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="','"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="element(Level)*">
        <xsl:param name="levels" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$levels" group-by="substring(., 1, 1)">
            <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key() != ''">
                <Level index="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest(current-group() ! substring(., 2))"/>
                </Level>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="rows" as="element(row)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="levels" as="element(Level)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="index" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:variable name="current-level" as="element(Level)?" select="$levels[1]"/>
        <xsl:if test="$current-level">
            <xsl:variable name="indices-of-current-level" select="$current-level/Level/@index!(. + $index)"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="cell[position() = $indices-of-current-level]" composite="yes">
                <Level index="{$current-level/@index}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-grouping-key()">
                        <Data index="L{$current-level/@index}{position()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </Data>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $levels[position() gt 1], $index + count(current-grouping-key()))"/>
                </Level>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(., '(\r?\n)+')[normalize-space()]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="levels" select="tokenize(normalize-space($lines[1]), $sep)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="nesting" select="mf:nest($levels ! substring(., 2))"/>

        <xsl:variable name="data" select="$lines[position() gt 1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rows" as="element(row)*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$data">
                <row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(), $sep)">
                        <cell>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </cell>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <document>
            <!-- only for debugging respectively to show the intermediate XML data structure used for further processing -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$nesting"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$rows"/>

            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($rows, $nesting, 0)"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gives the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <Level index="1">
      <Level index="1"/>
      <Level index="2"/>
   </Level>
   <Level index="2">
      <Level index="1"/>
      <Level index="2"/>
   </Level>
   <Level index="3">
      <Level index="1"/>
      <Level index="2"/>
   </Level>
   <row>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>A</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>C</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>G</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>A</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>C</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>H</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>A</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>D</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>I</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>A</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>D</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>J</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>B</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>E</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>K</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>B</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>E</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>L</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>B</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>F</cell>
      <cell>1</cell>
      <cell>M</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>B</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>F</cell>
      <cell>2</cell>
      <cell>N</cell>
   </row>
   <Level index="1">
      <Data index="L11">1</Data>
      <Data index="L12">A</Data>
      <Level index="2">
         <Data index="L21">1</Data>
         <Data index="L22">C</Data>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">1</Data>
            <Data index="L32">G</Data>
         </Level>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">2</Data>
            <Data index="L32">H</Data>
         </Level>
      </Level>
      <Level index="2">
         <Data index="L21">2</Data>
         <Data index="L22">D</Data>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">1</Data>
            <Data index="L32">I</Data>
         </Level>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">2</Data>
            <Data index="L32">J</Data>
         </Level>
      </Level>
   </Level>
   <Level index="1">
      <Data index="L11">2</Data>
      <Data index="L12">B</Data>
      <Level index="2">
         <Data index="L21">1</Data>
         <Data index="L22">E</Data>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">1</Data>
            <Data index="L32">K</Data>
         </Level>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">2</Data>
            <Data index="L32">L</Data>
         </Level>
      </Level>
      <Level index="2">
         <Data index="L21">2</Data>
         <Data index="L22">F</Data>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">1</Data>
            <Data index="L32">M</Data>
         </Level>
         <Level index="3">
            <Data index="L31">2</Data>
            <Data index="L32">N</Data>
         </Level>
      </Level>
   </Level>
</document>
```

using Saxon PE 9.6 in Oxygen 18 or the XSLT 3.0 processor in Altova XMLSpy 2017. You can of course remove the lines outputting the intermediate data structure and you can change the creation of the final XML to output elements names containing the level in the name but I prefer to have names that can be represented by a schema and to put any counter or level index into an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll upvote it but I cannot use XSLT 3.0, I should have mentioned it in the question. I am using a system that doesn't support v.3.0.