# Transform csv to xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-1.0

Following the approach described in: [Converting CSV to hierarchichal XML using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506228/converting-csv-to-hierarchichal-xml-using-xslt)

Now, raw input file would contain empty tokens as below:

```
<root>
GroupName,GroupValue,SubGroupName,SubGroupValue,ItemName,ItemValue
,A,1,C,1,G
1,,1,C,2,H
1,A,2,D,1,I
</root>
```

And the original XSLT 1.0 provided is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="row" use="cell[1]"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="row" use="concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- tokenize csv -->
    <xsl:variable name="rows">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="root"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="data">
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rows)/row[position() > 1]">
            <row>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'cell'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <document>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($data)/row[count(. | key('k1', cell[1])[1]) = 1]">
            <group>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cell[1]"/>
                </name>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cell[2]"/>
                </value>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', cell[1])[count(. | key('k2', concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3]))[1]) = 1]">
                    <subgroup>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[3]"/>
                        </name>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[4]"/>
                        </value>
                        <items>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('k2', concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3]))">
                                <item>
                                    <name>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="cell[5]"/>
                                    </name>
                                    <value>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="cell[6]"/>
                                    </value>
                                </item>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </items>
                    </subgroup>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="name" select="'row'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to tweak the xslt so that it would NOT skip empty tokens in this scenario and produce the following xml output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <data>
  <GroupName></GroupName>
  <GroupValue>A</GroupValue>
  ...
  </data>

  <data>
  <GroupName>1</GroupName>
  <GroupValue></GroupValue>
  ...
  </data>

  <data>
  <GroupName>1</GroupName>
  <GroupValue>A</GroupValue>
  ...
  </data>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

also you can check this at http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWt1/2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="elements">
        <element>GroupName</element>
        <element>GroupValue</element>
        <element>SubGroupName</element>
        <element>SubGroupValue</element>
        <element>ItemName</element>
        <element>ItemValue</element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <Document>
            <xsl:call-template name="row">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </Document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="row">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($data, '&#xa;')">
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-before($data, '&#xa;')) != ''">
                    <data>
                        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
                            <xsl:with-param name="celldata" select="substring-before($data, '&#xa;')"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </data>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-after($data, '&#xa;')) != ''">
                    <xsl:call-template name="row">
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring-after($data, '&#xa;')"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($data) != ''">
                    <data>
                        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
                            <xsl:with-param name="celldata" select="$data"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </data>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cell">
        <xsl:param name="celldata"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($celldata, ',')">
                <xsl:element name="{exsl:node-set($elements)//element[position() = $position]}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($celldata, ',')"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:call-template name="cell">
                    <xsl:with-param name="celldata" select="substring-after($celldata, ',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="number($position) + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{$elements//element[position() = $position]}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$celldata"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Did you try this with a XSLT 1.0 processor?

Comment: @DanielHaley, I have updated answer. you can see transform with Saxon 6.5.5 processor at [http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWt1/2](http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWt1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using this to be comment, but not sure how to format code via comment:
Thanks Rupesh, but what if 
1) only a few fields are selected to be in the output file, also, 
2)fields name could be required to change to other name in the output?

For 1), changing the xsl to the below to output only 3 selected fields

```
<xsl:variable name="elements">
    <element>SubGroupName</element>
    <element>ItemName</element>
    <element>ItemValue</element>
</xsl:variable>
```

it doesn't work?

For 2), let's say, GroupValue is renamed to "Field1" in output, and "ItemName" is renamed to "Field2" in output and those are the only 2 fields to be required...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <data>
  <Field1>A</Field1>
  <Field2>1</Field2>
  </data>

  <data>
  <Field1></Field1>
  <Field2>2</Field2>
  </data>

  <data>
  <Field1>A</Field1>
  <Field2>1</Field2>
  </data>

</Document>
```

Lastly, input fields might contain space, e.g.

```
<root>
Group Name,Group Value,Sub Group Name,Sub Group Value,Item Name,Item Value
,A,1,C,1,G 
1,,1,C,2,H
1,A,2,D,1,I
</root>
```